# Spezielle Bedeutung von »Aedificium«

Tags: meaning, latin

In *Der Name Der Rose* von Umberto Eco, in Übersetzung von Burkhart Kroeber, findet sich in der Beschreibung der Klosteranlage folgende Passage (und die Abbildung, hier aus einer englischen Ausgabe, im Anhang):

> Auf die Anlage der Abtei werde ich noch verschiedentlich zu sprechen kommen, hier mag ein erster Überblick genügen.
>   Am Torbau (der einzigen Öffnung in der Umfassungsmauer) begann eine von Bäumen gesäumte Allee, die zur Kirche des Klosters führte.
>   Zur Linken dieser Allee erstreckten sich in einem weiten Halbkreis Obst- und Gemüsegärten (darunter, wie ich später erfuhr, auch der hortulus botanicus), begrenzt von zwei flachen Gebäuden vor der nordwestlichen Mauer, dem Hospital und dem Badehaus.
>   Im Hintergrund, links von der Kirche und durch ein Gräberfeld von ihr getrennt, erhob sich gewaltig das **Aedificium**.
>   Das Nordtor der Kirche öffnete sich zum Südturm des massiven Quaders, der seinen Westturm frontal dem Blick des Besuchers darbot, links mit der Umfassungsmauer verschmelzend und hinter ihr, hoch gekrönt vom gerade noch sichtbaren Nordturm, den steil abfallenden Hang überragend.
>   Rechts von der Kirche, an ihre Südwand gelehnt, gruppierten sich einige Bauten um einen offenen Hof mit Kreuzgang – ohne Zweifel das Dormitorium, die Wohnung des Abtes und die Unterkünfte der Pilger, zu denen wir nun durch einen lieblichen Garten geleitet wurden.

[image]

Einfach nur als *Gebäude* scheint es in der Passage keinen Sinn zu ergeben, da dieser Ausdruck unpräziser ist als Kirche, Badehaus, Hospital, Wohnung, Dormitorium: Man würde sich unwillkürlich fragen, um was für eine Art Gebäude es sich handelt.
Zugleich ist es stark hervorgehoben (etwa im Vergleich zu »gruppierten sich einige Bauten«).
Es wirkt so, als hätte jede Abtei neben der Kirche, den Gemüsegärten etc. auch ein Aedificium, und als diene es einem bestimmten Zweck.

Leider helfen die üblichen Quellen nicht weiter.
Weder der Wahrig (1974) noch das Fremdwörterbuch vom Duden (1997) haben einen Eintrag dafür (egal ob mit Æ, Ae, Ä oder E).
Der Duden Online, Wiktionary und das DWDS kennen es auch nicht.
Im [Latin Dictionary](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:aedificium) steht nur *building*.
Im Oxford English Dictionary (Compact Edition) steht es unter *edifice* (mit Verweis auf *ædificium*) als *building*, oft im Sinne von Kirche, Palast etc., aber ohne erhellenden Hinweis auf eine spezifischere Verwendung.

Was für ein Gebäude ist ein Aedificium, welchem Zweck dient es?
Gibt es eine speziell kirchliche Bedeutung, die über *Gebäude* hinausgeht und die die Verwendung in der obigen Passage erklärt?

Comment: Wörter werden bisweilen in spezifischen Sonderbedeutungen verwandt, die enger sind als ihre Grundbedeutungen: *Haiserl* (Häuschen) in süddeutschen Dialekten bedeutet allgemein "kleines Haus", meint konkret aber die (separat im Garten stehende) Toilette. Aedificium bedeutet allgemein Gebäude, mag aber (und wenn Eco das verwendet, wird's schon so sein) auch in Gebrauch gewesen sein für das Hauptgebäude einer Kloster- und/oder Burganlage. Das ist im Moment leider nur eine Vermutung, ich habe keine bessere Kenntnis, die ich hier anbringen könnte.

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage Danke, das ist ein sehr hilfreicher Essay! Du hättest den deinem Zitat vorangehenden Satz aber ruhig mitzitieren können: »He knowingly uses an anachronism and invents his own building type.«

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage Magst du eine Antwort daraus machen?

Comment: @Philipp _"Aedificium"_ ist nicht wirklich ein _Lehnwort_ im Deutschen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Stimmt, ich habe den *tag* entfernt.

Comment: Meine Ausgabe (die von Zweitausendeins) hat nach den Übersetzungen der lateinischen Passagen auf Seite 645 noch ein Glossar. Erster Eintrag: "_Aedificium_ Gebäude, hier das Hauptgebäude der Klosteranlage".

Comment: @Matthias Tatsächlich, das hat meine Ausgabe auch. Ich hatte das Buch nicht vor dem Lesen durchgeblättert ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es ist wohl einfach das Hauptgebäude des Klosters.

Das lateinische Wort bedeutet neutral 'Gebäude' und selbst im italienischen Original verwendete Eco das italienische Wort für 'Gebäude'.

Bei Eco ist das Gebäude ein Anachronismus. Er ließ sich bei dem Aufbau des *Aedificiums* von [Castel del Monte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castel_del_Monte,_Apulia) inspirieren.

Roy MacLeod schreibt in *The Library of Alexandria: Centre of Learning in the Ancient World* (New York, 2000), S. 164 ([link](https://books.google.de/books?id=TT8BAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA164&ots=Wvtq-Ke3AE&dq=eco%20aedificium&hl=de&pg=PA164#v=onepage&q=eco%20aedificium&f=false)):

> For a start, it is located on the top floor of a building called an *aedificium*, which had been 'in centuries past ... a fortress', above the scriptorium and, below that, the kitchen. In classical Latin, the term *aedificum* is a neutral word. It just means 'a building'. In fact, in the Italian original of the *Name of the Rose*, the word used is 'edificio' - the normal Italian word for 'building'.

Eine nähere Erklärung gibt Vanessa Werder in *The Name of the Rose - The Monastic, Labyrinthine Library and a Comparison of its Illustration in the Book and the Movie* (digital Architectural Papers, 2012, [link](https://www.architecturalpapers.ch/pdf.php?ID=75)):

> He knowingly uses an anachronism and invents his own building type. The combination of kitchen and library would have never been housed in the same building, because the fire would be too big a risk for the valuable books stored in the library. Though Eco illustrates the Aedificium as a symbol for the oppositional struggle between carnal and spiritual desires within human beings.

Übersetzungen ins Deutsche:

1. Aus dem Lateinischen: *Aedificium* bedeutet "Gebäude, Bauwerk" ([Langenscheidt](https://de.langenscheidt.com/latein-deutsch/aedificium#sense-1.1.1))
2. Aus dem Italienischen: *Edificio* bedeutet "Gebäude, Bau, Bauwerk; Aufbau, Gefüge" ([Langenscheidt](https://de.langenscheidt.com/italienisch-deutsch/edificio#sense-1.2.1))

Ich habe die, in der Frage zitierte, Seite in der italienischen Ausgabe *Il nome della rosa* ([google books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=4KagDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT315&vq=edificio&hl=nl&pg=PT40#v=snippet&q=edificio%20tombe&f=false)) gefunden und Eco schreibt in der Tat *edificio*:

> A sinsitra del viale si stendeva una vasta zona di orti e, come poi seppi, il giardino botanico, intorno ai due edifici dei balnea e dell'ospedale ed erboristeria, che costeggiavano la curva delle mura. Sul fondo, a sinistra, si ergeva l'Edificio, separato dalla chiesa da una spianata coperta di tombe. Il portale nord della chiesa guardava il torrione sud dell'Edificio, che offriva frontalmente agli occhi del visitatore il torrione occidentale, quindi a sinistra si legava alle mura e sprofondava turrito verso l'abisso, su cui sie protendeva il torrione settentrionale, che si vedeva die sghimbescio.

Zusätzlich findet das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r?h=1&corpus=kern&from=&q=aedificium) ein Mal *Aedificium* auf S. 2667 des *Brockhaus-Riemann Musiklexikons D* von 1989:

> Nach H. Finck (1556) sollte die D. der Baßstimme vermieden werden, da man über einem instabile fundamentum kein stabile aedificium bauen könne;

Comment: Die deutsche Wikipedia, in dem [Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Name_der_Rose) zu *Der Name der Rose*, nennt es auch "Hauptgebäude der Klosteranlage" (siehe Abbildung des Labyrinths).

Answer (score 4):

Aedeficium vielleicht auch von seiner etymologischen Herkunft, aus dem Wort facere, etwas machen, herstellen. Die Unterscheidung von scholastischer Geistlichkeit und Mechanik wird im Prolog des Romans an William thematisch. Auch strenge Mönche müssen wohnen. Die Architektur gehört aber nicht zu den freien Künsten sondern zur Mechanik. Vielleicht errichtet Eco damit eine Spannung zwischen den mechanischen und freien Künsten über dieses zentrale Gebäude der Abtei.